# Passing XML string as an argument to Process.Start

Tags: c#, cmd, process.start

I am trying to use a string containing XML as an argument when calling Process.Start, however only characters up to the first space get through. For example if Input.xml contained the following text `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` all the application I'm calling receives is `"<?xml"`.

Here's the sample of the code to put this into context:

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load("C:/Input.xml");
        Process proc = Process.Start("C:/Program.exe", xml.OuterXml);
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is this your program? If so, change it to accept a filename or read from standard input - having an XML content as a command-line argument is *weird*.

Comment: You're right Jon, but this is as part of a temporary workaround.

Comment: So can you change the program? If so, use one of the alternatives - a temporary workaround is no good if it's a pain to use in itself.

Comment: Last week I gave up trying to pass the XML as argument and made changes to read from standard input. Jon, can you post your comment as an answer? Or maybe this question should be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to pass the XML data as a command line argument is basically a recipe for problems. You'll run into escaping problems all over the place, and probably command line length limits too.

Either read from standard input or a filename. At that point, it's pretty easy - a file is generally simpler than providing data to stdin, but both are feasible.

Answer (score 2):

```
Process proc = Process.Start("C:/Program.exe", String.Concat("\"", xml.OuterXml,"\"");
```

ie wrap the argument in quotes.

Nothing to do with xml arguments ina command line are delimited by spaces.

Comment: But the XML contains quotes `"`, won't that be a problem?

Comment: Almost certainly, but escaping all the quotes in the argument(s) is an other question. Not knowing that space is the argument delimiter on a command line needs to be understood first. Like others I'd use a file for this. Xml snippet with no attributes at all is a possiblity, but that's just a design flaw waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

When passing the arguments, standard rules apply, and when the string contain spaces, it's broken into multiple arguments.

You could try:

```
 Process proc = Process.Start("C:/Program.exe", "\"" + xml.OuterXml + "\"");
```

but then your xml contains `"` characters as well, and it breaks again. You could do something about it, but...it's not worth the effort. Just pass the filename as an argument and load xml in your program (if you can modify it).